# "manifest error" signing ZIP with BlackBerry WebWorks SDK bbwp tool

Tags: blackberry, sign, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

I've been following the [BlackBerry online docs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23977/Sign_the_cod_file_for_a_BB_Widget_application_836008_11.jsp) to build and test a WebWorks application.  Unfortunately I'm hitting a `manifest error: Invalid value '2.0.10' for Package-Version.`

Here's the detailed output:

```
C:\BB>bbwp.exe "helloworld.zip" -gcsk <snip> -gp12 <snip> -buildId 10 -o "output"
[INFO]                  Parsing command line options
[INFO]                  Parsing bbwp.properties
[INFO]                  Validating WebWorks archive
[INFO]                  Parsing config.xml
[INFO]                  Populating application source
[INFO]                  Compiling WebWorks application
[INFO]                  Packaging the bar file
[INFO]                  Bar packaging complete
[INFO]                  Starting signing tool
manifest error:
Invalid value '2.0.10' for Package-Version.
[ERROR]                 Signing failed
```

The only place that I can see "2.0" appearing is in my config.xml file:

```
<widget xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
        version="2.0">
```

Does anybody know if I've missed a config step?

I am using 64 bit Windows 7 with Java 1.6.0_21, but I doubt that should matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical, I knew I would figure this out as soon as I posted the question...

I found another [BlackBerry webpage](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23977/Compile_a_BlackBerry_Widget_application_834647_11.jsp) that explains the buildId in more detail:

> -buildId
>
> For signed applications, this
>   parameter specifies the build number.
>   Typically, this number should be
>   incremented from the previous signed
>   application.
>
> If you specified a version number in
>   the config.xml file, the build number
>   you specify becomes the fourth digit
>   of the version number. For example,
>   either 1.2.0 or 1.2.0.1 (in
>   config.xml) become 1.2.0.7 if you
>   specify a build number of 7.
>
> If you do not specify a build number,
>   the version number stays the same (if
>   it is four digits long) or a fourth
>   digit of 0 is added (if it is three
>   digits long). For example, 1.2.0.1
>   remains the same, and 1.2.0 becomes
>   1.2.0.0.

I tried changing my config.xml version to have three digits, and then the signing step worked.

```
<widget xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
        version="2.0.0">
```

New output from the tool:

```
<snip>
[INFO]                  Starting signing tool
[INFO]                  Signing complete
[INFO]                  WebWorks application packaging complete
```

It's good to see that the original [config.xml sample from BlackBerry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/15369/Sample_widget_configuration_document_834683_11.jsp) doesn't work! :-)